# Bootstrap Carousel and thumbnail images to work together

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I succeeded without problems to launch the carousel in it standard form. Now, I would like to use the thumbnails below the carousel to select and force the image I want to see. This feature is on top of what exists within the carousel already. Ideally I wish to have a also an "active" class that I can use on the thumbnails to highlight which thumbnail I currently have on display in the carousel. 
If somebody can help me for this next step.
thanks a lot
Peter

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap tests</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <h1>test Carousel</h1>
    <div class="row">               
                <div >
                    <carousel interval="myInterval">
                      <slide ng-repeat="image in images" active="image.active">
                        <img ng-src="{{image.image}}" >
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <p>{{image.text}}</p>
                        </div>
                      </slide>
                    </carousel>
                </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="row" style="background-color:sienna">   
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" ng-repeat="image in images"  ng-click="select(slide)">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="{{image.thumbnail}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div<  
</div>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript"              src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/servicesGetImages.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you found a way to use thumbnails? I am trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

use ng-class here like this:

```
<slide ng-repeat="image in images" ng-class="{ active : 'image.active'}">
```